# JSF/SEAM: How to pre-select checkboxes in a form

Tags: java, jsf, seam

I have a form where i have to preselect some checkboxes. How is that possible with jsf/seam? In plain html you would just add the "checked" (or checked="checked") as attribute to the checkboxes. But with f:selectItems I have no clue...also the Object "SelectItem" does not provide any setter for this...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to preset them in the property behind the component's `value` attribute as you usually do for every `UIInput` component. You can do that in the bean's constructor or initialization block.

Here's a basic example:

```
<h:selectManyCheckbox value="#{bean.selectedItems}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.selectItems}" />
</h:selectManyCheckbox>
```

Bean:

```
private List<String> selectedItems; // +getter +setter.
private List<SelectItem> selectItems; // +getter.

public Bean() {
    // Preset the selected items.
    this.selectedItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    this.selectedItems.add("valueToBePreselected1");
    this.selectedItems.add("valueToBePreselected2");
    // Those values should be exactly the same as one of the SelectItem values.
    // I.e. the Object#equals() must return true for any of them.
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Actually I tried this already and it didn't work because I.....added the labels of the checkboxes, not the values ;).

Answer (score 1):

Populate the property you use in "value" before rendereing the page (for example using a phase listener)

```
<h:selectManyCheckbox value="#{selectManyCheckBoxBean.selectedItems}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="India" itemValue="India" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="China" itemValue="China" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Germany" itemValue="Germany" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="USA" itemValue="USA" />
</h:selectManyCheckbox>
```